# How can I place a column with three vertical images and a column with bulleted text in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

Title says it all! I would like to have text in one column on the left, and then have three images on the right to show the 3 study species in question. I am very new to LaTeX so I am not sure how to format this and make it look pretty.

Thank you for any help! I've attached a picture from PowerPoint to show what I'd like to do in Beamer.[image: What I'm Looking For]

Comment: [Beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section 12.7 for columns. Three `\includegraphics` commands separated by paragraph breaks in the second column. Section 3.8 for the frame title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create columns with the `columns` environment and putting each column's content in its own `column` environment.  You specify the column width in its mandatory argument.  In the case below, I use `0.5\linewidth` for both of them but you could easy have the text wider and the images narrower for example.

By default, the columns are vertically centred but if you want for the tops to line up, use `\begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}` instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Emily}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Lorem
      \item Ipsum
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Dolor
        \item Sit
        \end{itemize}
      \item Amet
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=6em]{example-image-a}

      \includegraphics[height=6em]{example-image-b}

      \includegraphics[height=6em]{example-image-c}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! I copied your code, but my images are showing up horizontally and not vertically?